# Iteration over groups and writing the function

Tags: python, pandas

Hi there I have a bit of a dilemma that I am hoping someone can solve. I would like to perform a function over each group and transform the results back into the main dataframe. Consider the dataframe below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[A,0.7,0.9,0.2],[A,0.7,0.9,0.2],[A,0.7,0.9,0.2],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2]], columns=['group', 'P','PP','P-P'])
df['index']=df.groupby(['group']).cumcount()
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

So I want to run the same iteration over both group==A and group==B. The iteration I want to run is as follows:

1. the first value of the new variable must be equal to the first value 'P'.
2. Every value after that will be the preceding value of 'P' multiplied by 'PP' plus 1 minus the preceding value of 'P' multiplied by 'P-P'.

The answer should look like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[A,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.7],[A,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.69],[A,0.7,0.9,0.2,0.683],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.6],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.62],[B,0.6,0.9,0.2,0.634]], columns=['group', 'P','PP','P-P','ANS'])
df['index']=df.groupby(['group']).cumcount()
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

Assuming this is the proper order...

I attempted to solve this by doing the foll0wing loop:

```
grouped=df.groupby('group')
for name, group in grouped:
for i in range(1,group.shape[0]):
   group.loc[0,'ANS']=group.loc[0,'P']

   group.loc[i,'ANS']=group.loc[i-1,'ANS']*group.loc[i,'PP']+(1-group.loc[i-1,'ANS'])*group.loc[i,'P-P']

print(group)
```

But this only returns group B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a function you want to apply to the group and pass it into `apply`, as such

```
def my_func(group):
    for i in range(1,group.shape[0]):
        group.loc[0,'ANS']=group.loc[0,'P']
        group.loc[i,'ANS']=group.loc[i-1,'ANS']*group.loc[i,'PP']+(1-group.loc[i-1,'ANS'])*group.loc[i,'P-P']
    return group
df.groupby('group').apply(my_func)
```

returns

```
    group   P   PP  P-P ANS
index                   
0   A       0.7 0.9 0.2 0.700
1   A       0.7 0.9 0.2 0.690
2   A       0.7 0.9 0.2 0.683
0   B       0.6 0.9 0.2 0.600
1   B       0.6 0.9 0.2 0.620
2   B       0.6 0.9 0.2 0.634
```

Comment: @wildwest feel free to 'accept' the answer if it was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers